# browser.switchTo().alert() not working in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, webdriver, protractor

browser.switchTo().alert() not working in protractor.

sample code:

```
browser.get('http://google.com');
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Message:

```
UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open
(Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
 Stacktrace:
   UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open


C:\Users\Vikas.Gahlaut\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open
```

Tried everything and it is not related to chrome driver issue as same is working fine with webdriver-java native APIs.

Comment: Are you sure there is an alert opened?

Comment: Yes alecxe,It's an alert as I am able to handle it using webdriver's API, driver.switchTo().alert().accept() but not with protractor and the error also says unexpected alert open

Answer (score 4):

Unless you've set `ignoreSynchronization`, the fact that you're navigating to a non angular app (google.com) is messing it up.

Try

```
browser.driver.get('http://google.com');
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

or

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
browser.get('http://google.com');
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: This is not working in chrome, could you please help me...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779693/unexpected-alert-open-error-browser-switchto-alert-accept-works-fine-i

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the alert takes a time until it appears, you can try adding a wait before you make an accept:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
browser.get('http://google.com');
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 10000);
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, so that it does not fail if no alert is open:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get('http://google.com');
browser.switchTo().alert().then(function() {
    browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
}, function(){});
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    browser.get("your.address.com");

    browser.switchTo().alert().then(function(alert) {
        alert.accept();
    }).catch(function(error) {

    });
```