# How to click OK in alert box using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using AngularJS and I want to delete a link, in such cases, an alert box appears to confirm the delete.

I am trying to do e2e test using protractor, how do I confirm in an alert box?

I tried:

```
browser.switchTo().alert().accept()
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a provision in protractor for handling alert boxes?

Answer (score 6):

try

```
browser.driver.get('URL');
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

or

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
browser.get('URL');
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

or : [browser.switchTo().alert() not working in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941510/browser-switchto-alert-not-working-in-protractor)

Comment: Still I get an error  "UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open"

Comment: @PrateekChoudhury did you find a solution ?

Comment: Don't use ignoreSynchronization. Current version requires `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 6):

[Wait for alert to become present](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.alertIsPresent):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 5000, "Alert is not getting present :(")
```

Answer (score 3):

Set up a promise to wait for the alert to be present:

```
function getAlertAndClose(element) {
    return element.click().then(function (alertText) {
        //Wait for alert to pop up
        browser.wait(function () {
            return browser.switchTo().alert().then(
                function () {return true;},
                function () {return false;}
            );
        }, 3000); // Wait timeout

        // Test alert is what you expect
        var popupAlert = browser.switchTo().alert();
        alertText = popupAlert.getText();
        expect(alertText).toMatch('Are you sure you want to delete this?');

        // Close alert
        popupAlert.dismiss();
    })
}

var saveButton = $('.saveBtn');
getAlertAndClose(saveButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine:

```
await browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Answer (score 0):

**This thing is wroking fine i have tried it**

---

```
 await browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```