# Unexpected Alert Open Error. "browser.switchTo().alert().accept();" works fine in firefox but not in Chrome when running through Jenkins

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

How to handle this error in chrome browser using protractor.
[image]

Chrome driver through's following error: **UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : There are unsaved data, please save before you leave, otherwise your changes get lost!}**
I have used "browser.switchTo().alert().accept();" but this is not working, works fine in firefox. Please help me, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is that this is a bug introduced in Chrome 52. I am struggling with the same issues described here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=632024

Comment: To add some detail, I am using Chrome to test an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Selenium. Tests were fine until my PC upgraded Chrome to 52. Some of my tests involve purposefully calling `IWebDriver.Navigate().Back()` to trigger a dirty forms alert. Where previously this call would succeed and I could then check for the expected alert and handle it, now the call to `IWebDriver.Navigate().Back()` results in an `InvalidOperationException` thrown by `OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError`. Chromedriver is version 2.23.409699, Selenium is version 2.53.1 and Chrome is 52.0.2743.116.

Comment: I have chrome=49.0.2623.110, and when i run locally it works fine but when i trigger it through Jenkins(head less browser) it through error.

Comment: @Speedbird186 can we send "Enter" key to accept alert?
I don't have any webElement.

Comment: I haven't tried that, because in my case I actually need to know if the alert was there

Answer (score 2):

today, after struggling with this new problem for the past week or so, we found that the problem was fixed by using the latest Protractor version. Changing the package.json to  "protractor": "*" did the job.